# Android Kotlin: Compare two .wav audio files for similarity

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text, fingerprint

I need to compare two short .wav audio files for similarity (fingerprint) and return a matching score.

The audio files contains a recorded Android's text-to-speech short phrase and the same user's phrase recorder by mic with this great [OmRecorder](https://github.com/kailash09dabhi/OmRecorder) library, and the idea is to compare them and give a result as a part of my "Listen and repeat" English lessons attempt.

I cannot dive in the world of FFT as it is too complex and time consuming for me, so I'ld like to find a library for that purpose.

The only I've found so far is [musicg](https://github.com/loisaidasam/musicg), but it's not working for me, as it's always returning 0 or the same fixed 0.047 number.

The Kotlin code I'm using for the comparison is:

```
val w1 = Wave(this.cacheDir.toString() + "/file1.wav")
val w2 = Wave(this.cacheDir.toString() + "/file2.wav")
println("Wave 1 = " + w1.waveHeader)
println("Wave 2 = " + w2.waveHeader)
val fpsc1: FingerprintSimilarity = w1.getFingerprintSimilarity(w2)
val scorec = fpsc1.score
val simc = fpsc1.similarity
(findViewById<View>(R.id.tvScore) as TextView).text = scorec.toString()
(findViewById<View>(R.id.tvSimilarity) as TextView).text = simc.toString()
```

While debugging I was able to verify both audios have the same settings, or at least this is what debugger shows while inspecting "Wave" objects:

File 1:

```
chunkId: RIFF
chunkSize: 53286
format: WAVE
subChunk1Id: fmt 
subChunk1Size: 16
audioFormat: 1
channels: 1
sampleRate: 10240
byteRate: 20480
blockAlign: 2
bitsPerSample: 16
subChunk2Id: data
subChunk2Size: 53250
length: 2.6000977
```

File 2:

```
chunkId: RIFF
chunkSize: 24378
format: WAVE
subChunk1Id: fmt 
subChunk1Size: 16
audioFormat: 1
channels: 1
sampleRate: 10240
byteRate: 20480
blockAlign: 2
bitsPerSample: 16
subChunk2Id: data
subChunk2Size: 24342
length: 1.1885742
```

This is the fragment of code I use to start recording (you can see audio settings here):

```
private var recorder: Recorder? = null

private fun startRecording() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        return
    }

    val file: String = this.cacheDir.toString() + "/file2.wav"

    recorder = OmRecorder.wav(
        PullTransport.Default(
            mic()
        ) { audioChunk -> animateVoice((audioChunk.maxAmplitude() / 200.0).toFloat()) }, File(file)
    )

    recorder!!.startRecording()
}

private fun mic(): PullableSource {
    return PullableSource.Default(
        AudioRecordConfig.Default(
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, 8000
        )
    )
}

private fun animateVoice(maxPeak: Float) {
    (findViewById<View>(R.id.microphone) as ImageView).animate().scaleX(1 + maxPeak).scaleY(1 + maxPeak).setDuration(10).start()
}
```

I've found many Python libraries for this, like [this one](https://github.com/charlesconnell/AudioCompare), but curiously only one for Android, and it's not working for me.

I know my goal is not trivial at all, but it's not impossible.

What can I try next?